# how to convert string into DateTime in where Clause?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, entity-framework

i have to compare a choosen Date from a Calendar (startdat & enddat) with a Date in my SQL 2008 R2 DB. I have to write it with LINQ, but in the view i have, the DateTime is converted to a String (Varchar) so i have to convert it in my LINQ Query back to DateTime. My basic Query looks like this now:

```
var reportlist = (from r in context.Monthly_Report
                  where r.CreateDate >= startdat && r.CreateDate <= enddat
                  select r.Ticketnumber).ToList();
```

So the `CreateDate` i get is a `String` and for comparing i've to convert it. I've tried it with `Convert.ToDateTime()` but there's is the Problem with L2E.
So how can i convert it like in a SQL Script or that SQL knows what i means?

Thanks for every help i get. (btw i'm not allowed to change the view)

Comment: Is there any way you can change the view? It's not just a matter of LINQ - fundamentally if the field is a date, it shouldn't be returned as a string.

Comment: @mxmissile Someone makes a poor design decision, so now you advocate firing them? Don't you think that's a bit harsh? Clearly it's a bad idea, but everyone goes through a lot of bad ideas when they're learning

Comment: @JonSkeet as i understand OP has date stored as string in the database

Comment: You can create another proxy view that will transform string back to date

Comment: you can try to use [EntityFunctions.CreateDateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.createdatetime(v=vs.110).aspx) but it would be ugly

Comment: @GuruStron: Well it specifically talks about a view. But wherever it's being specified as a varchar, it shouldn't be...

Comment: @JonSkeet also he says that `CreateDate` is `String` but I totally agree that it shouldn't be)

Comment: in the tables it is a DateTime and please don't ask me why they converted it in the View but however, i've to work with it....

and i still don't find the reason why they converted the Date - it's always a back and forth between varchar and datetime.

Comment: if `CreateDate` in your context is DateTime then convert `startdat & enddat` before the LINQ query

Comment: @GuruStron `CreateDate` is a String now and `startdat`/`enddat` is DateTime. I can't compare string Dates....if it would work it would be to easy

Comment: You have to drop back to ADO.NET and raw SQL then use `CAST` or `CONVERT` in your raw query.

Comment: as i mentioned before you can try to use `EntityFunctions.CreateDateTime` in your query or you can select all data to memory(if there is not much) and work with it in your app or you can write you query in code in raw sql and execute it.

Comment: Another solution is using substrings, and reordering the "stringified" date of the db, so that it has the format "yyyymmdd" (this will be transalted to DB functions wihout problem). Then you need to express the startdat and enddat in the same format and compare in alphabetic order. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use a reduced set of functions in Linq to Entities. This functions will be transalated to DB functions.

You can use:

- [canonical functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738626.aspx): they're availabel for all the providers (DB tastes)
- [entity functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): exposes canonical functions in the EDM
- [db functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions%28v=vs.113%29.aspx): exposes canonical functions in the EDM
- [sql functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): exposes SQL Server specific functions

None of these groups includes a function that can convert from string to datetime, so there is no way to do it directly.

You must look for alternatives:

- Create a DB view which exposes the "stringified" datetime as a datetimecolumn and query it
- Create a stored proc and use it
- Convert the datetime to string and compare it, if at all possible (this depends on how the "stringified" datetime looks like)
- You can use the previous solution using substrings (which will map to DB functions). This will work for all cases: reorder the y, m, d, of the "stringified" dt date, so that it looks like "yyyymmdd". Then convert your `startdat` and `enddat` to the same format, and compare it in string (alphabetic) order.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, you need your view to return a datetime.

However, there are a couple of ways to do this.

1) You could pull your data out as a string into a list object.  Then you wouldnt be using L2E.

```
var temp = (from r in context.Monthly_Report
            select new { r.Ticketnumber,  r.CreateDate} ).ToList();
var reportList = temp.Where(r =>  
                            Convert.ToDateTime(r.CreateDate) >= startdat && 
                            Convert.ToDateTime(r.CreateDate) <= enddat)
```

2) You could convert your datetime to a string value and compare it.

```
var reportlist = (from r in context.Monthly_Report
                  where r.CreateDate.CompareTo(startdatasstring) >= 0 && 
                        r.CreateDate.CompareTo(enddatasstring)  <= 0
                  select r.Ticketnumber).ToList();
```

Comment: what if there is millions of rows? you just killed his app

Comment: @mxmissile, my first line is real answer.  There is a big problem with the way that the data is handled.  That said, if he doesnt have a choice, these are alternatives.

Comment: 1) i've tried this one but there's an exception with LINQ to Entities - it says that SQL doesn't understand the `Convert.ToDateTime()`
2) why should `>= 0` help? i need all ticketnumbers which are older than the `startdat` and younger than the `enddat`.

Comment: @papogomez if he is "required" to use LINQ you are correct, however there are other valid solutions.

Comment: @mxmissile, then post one.  I'll upvote it. :)  As it stands, i think mine is the only viable answer out there.

Comment: @DaveS. Its not `Convert` that is returning greater than or less than 0.  Its `CompareTo`.  Read closely.

Comment: @mxmissile i don't **HAVE TO** use LINQ but i'm using it - i thought it's easier for me because i worked with it in the hole project

Comment: @paqogomez version 1 isn't working - i mean there are no exceptions but the list is empty. I've proved so many ways in SQLMS but nothing works in LINQ with this stupid string date -.- i'm pissed

Comment: @DaveS. Have you looked at the list returned from the first query?  Are there SUPPOSED to be results?  What are the values of `startdat` and `enddat`?